# Physical Object Detector

Tags: barcode-scanner

Is there a device like barcode reader which detect physical objects with webcam or something like that? I am using a barcode reader for a supermarket and my barcode reader can't read some of the barcodes. My barcode reader is fine, the problem is with my stuffs' barcodes. Is there a hardware or even software to detect the whole objects for me?
thanx in advance

Comment: you might also want to check if rfid tags are the thing for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object recognition is a very complex field. Although what youa re looking  this is possible i doubt if they are commercially available. If even if it were available it would be really expensive..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SnapTell](http://www.snaptell.com/).  You can take a picture of an object, and they can find a match in a database.  It's pretty amazing.  It's all proprietary, but maybe they'll license their service.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial product available that is built to look underneath shopping carts and identify the merchandise by sight.  It's called [LaneHawk](http://www.evoretail.com/products/) and is made by Evolution Robotics.